# defining a function that gives me the distance between 2 dates

Tags: python, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oANOw.png)

I need to write a piece of code that calculates the distance between 2 dates, as shown in the screenshot above^

This is what I put:

```
def dist2dates(date1,date2):
    result= date2[0:2]-date1[0:2],"/",date2[3:]-date1[3:]
    return result

res2=dist2dates(1116,1129)
print(res2)
```

This produces an error that says:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong. Also, I am not too clear on how to put a date such as "08/16" in the argument? Can someone help me define such a function?

Comment: "08/16" is a string. You are expected to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
import re

def dist2dates(date1,date2):
    if re.match(r'^\d{2}\/\d{2}$', date1) and re.match(r'^\d{2}\/\d{2}$', date2):
        diff1 = abs(((int(date2[0:2])-int(date1[0:2]))))
        diff2 = abs((int(date2[3:])-int(date1[3:])))
        result= ("%02d/%02d") %(diff1, diff2)
        return result
    else:
        return "Incorrect format"

res2=dist2dates("11/16","11/29")
print(res2)
```

Output:

```
00/13
```

It always returns the absolute value abs(), so you wont get negative numbers. It also checks if the date string is formatted correctly using RegEx.

=================== Before edit =================

Try this:

```
def dist2dates(date1,date2):

    result= ("%02d/%02d") %(int(date2[0:2])-int(date1[0:2]) ,int(date2[3:])-int(date1[3:]))
    return result

res2=dist2dates("10/16","11/29")
print(res2)
```

Output:

```
01/13
```

The inputs to the dist2dates function should be strings not integers.

Cast the strings into integers so you can subtract the numbers.

Comment: @Chirs You're 100% right. I just edited the OPs original code. I want the code to be as close to his possible.

Comment: It does work however it produces negative numbers if date 2 is less than date 1, like Chris says. I don't know how to fix this because I haven't learned how to parse.. can someone show me?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The nature of this problem is sort of strange since now your year has 360 days, but this structure handles both if the first date is larger or smaller, it works by evaluating the difference in days based on 30 day months then converts them to days and uses zfill to print the output.

```
def dist2dates(a, b):
    a = list(map(int, a.split('/')))
    b = list(map(int, b.split('/')))
    if b[0] < a[0]:
        days = 360 - 30*(a[0] - b[0]) - (a[1] - b[1])
    else:
        days = 30*((b[0]- 1) - a[0]) + (30 - a[1]) + b[1]
    print(days)
    tup = divmod(days,30)
    mm, dd = tup[0], tup[1]    
    return f'{str(mm).zfill(2)}/{str(dd).zfill(2)}'

print(dist2dates('03/20', '01/10')) # => 09/20
print(dist2dates('01/12', '05/20')) # => 04/08
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use datetime module to calculate the timedelta & use the `strptime`/`strftime` for formatting?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def dist2dates(strdate1,strdate2):
    '''format mm/dd, assumes month = 30 days always'''
    dtfmt = '%m/%d'
    date1 = datetime.strptime(strdate1, dtfmt)
    date2 = datetime.strptime(strdate2, dtfmt)
    delta = date2 - date1
    year = date1.year
    month, day = divmod(delta.days, 30)
    result = datetime.strftime(datetime(year, round(month), round(day)), '%m/%d')
    return result

res = dist2dates('01/16','11/29')
print(res)
# 10/13
```